# Where can I find information on what ImageMagick procedure is called under the hood for Rmagick Image#difference method?

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I am assuming that the [Image#difference](https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#difference)-method of Rmagick is actually calling [compare](https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) from ImageMagick under the hood, but I can't find it in source code?

The reason why I'm interested is that I would like to have it `compare` using the command-line argument called [-subimage-search](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#subimage-search)

Comment: Grepping the source code and that method seems to be defined in a C file here: https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/blob/master/ext/RMagick/rmimage.c#L5266 What's actually happening here I haven't a clue but good luck.

Comment: Thanks! -> I would accept that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to assume. The [Image#difference](https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#difference) documentation notes that the difference method calls the ImageMagick API IsImagesEqual.

There is no single RMagick method that corresponds to ImageMagick's compare command. The compare command calls dozens of different ImageMagick APIs depending on the command options. Generally speaking, RMagick surfaces each one of those APIs as a method.